# How make a frame of cloth simulation into a permanent object?

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, cloth-simulation

I'm using the cloth modifier on a plane, and I was wondering if it is possible to take away the animation, with the default of that object being what it is in a frame of that animation.

[image: Bed After Animation]

I want the cloth to look like that in the beginning of the animation (or without an animation at all, really), where it looks like this:

[image: Bed Before Animation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **cloth** button in the physics tab creates a modifier linked to it.

Apply the modifier, your cache will be lost. It will be applied on the current frame.

[image]